# Ansible modules not working for adding a git-ppa - "W:GPG error - NO_PUBKEY" error

Tags: ubuntu, ansible, apt

My playbook with below tasks was running with success, a few months back.

```
- name: add git ppa repo
  apt_repository:
    repo: deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/git-core/ppa/ubuntu {{ ansible_lsb.codename }} main
    state:  present
  become: yes

- name: Add git apt key by id from a keyserver
  apt_key:
    keyserver: keyserver.ubuntu.com
    id: A1715D88E1DF1F24
    state: present
  become: yes
```

When i run this now it is breaking with error

> W: GPG error: http://ppa.launchpad.net/git-core/ppa/ubuntu bionic InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY A1715D88E1DF1F24
>   E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/git-core/ppa/ubuntu bionic InRelease' is not signed.

I am able to fix the error by running 
`sudo apt-key adv --recv-keys --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com A1715D88E1DF1F24`

If I do not want to run this as RAW/SHELL ansible command. Is there any other way to fix it and I am wondering what has gone wrong with the ansible apt_key section which I believe was doing the same thing before and was working. Thank you!

Comment: Reverse the order of the tasks?

Comment: thanks, clockworknet. yeah, that does not work either.

Answer (score 0):

I have similar problem with Ubuntu 18.04 in Win Bash and this solution work for me:

```
Err:2 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease
  The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 3B4FE6ACC0B21F32
Hit:6 http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/java/ubuntu bionic InRelease
Err:5 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/php/ubuntu bionic InRelease
  The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 4F4EA0AAE5267A6C
Err:6 http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/java/ubuntu bionic InRelease
  The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY C2518248EEA14886
Hit:7 http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/y-ppa-manager/ubuntu bionic InRelease
Err:3 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security InRelease
  The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 3B4FE6ACC0B21F32
Get:1 http://ppa.launchpad.net/linuxuprising/java/ubuntu bionic InRelease [15.9 kB]
Err:4 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates InRelease
  The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 3B4FE6ACC0B21F32
Err:7 http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/y-ppa-manager/ubuntu bionic InRelease
  The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY C2518248EEA14886
Err:1 http://ppa.launchpad.net/linuxuprising/java/ubuntu bionic InRelease
  The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY EA8CACC073C3DB2A
```

1. I try use apt-get update e get the error : couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 3B4FE6ACC0B21F32
2. So, I use curl -sL "http://keyserver.ubuntu.com/pks/lookup?op=get&search=0xREPLACENUMBERPUBKEY" | sudo apt-key add Replace 0x3B4FE6ACC0B21F32 with 0x
3. Sample: curl -sL "http://keyserver.ubuntu.com/pks/lookup?op=get&search=0x3B4FE6ACC0B21F32" | sudo apt-key add

Referente: https://github.com/Microsoft/WSL/issues/3286#issuecomment-402594992